# Is there a way to disable the black bars on the bottom/top of the screen?

Tags: ps3, the-evil-within

I can't seem to find any way to remove the ugly black bars that are on the top and bottom of the screen. Supposedly, this is used to create a more cinematic look, but to me personally it looks ugly, and takes up too much room on an already small screen space.

Is there a way to disable them?

Comment: [This link](http://www.pcgamer.com/the-evil-within-debug-console-commands-detailed-god-mode-is-in/) gives a way to do it on PC.  If it requires the debug console on PC, I doubt there's a way to do it on PS3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT: June 2015

*As of June 2015, the bars can now be disabled on all consoles via the settings. To disable*:

- Navigate to the Pause Menu
- Selection Options
- Select Graphics
- Select Letterbox
- Select Disable Letterbox

The following information is now **out of date** and should not be considered as the answer. It is left for archival purposes.

---

## This is not possbile for PS3

Though they state that it gives a more cinematic view, there is another reason why they did it.

---

## But Why?

By putting black bars on the top and bottom area, they can lower the amount of the game needing to be rendered at any time. Most PS3 renders the game at 720P.  This means the amount of pixels from top to bottom is:

```
720P Pixels
```

Hence the name 720P. The number of pixels from left to right is:

```
1280 Pixels
```

The total number of pixels on the screen being rendered at any time by most games is equal to:

```
1280 x 720 = 921600
```

> You can see the  this in the image below, showing the resolution and the number of pixels on both the height and width for the most widely-adopeted resolutions:
>   [image]
>
> ---

## So?

The problem is that the PS3 is incredibly old hardware, and such cannot render the game as good as they want to be with a low FPS. To combat this, they lowered the number of pixels being rendered by the PS3.

> **Without the black bars, the game could render like this:**
>   [image]
>   **With the black bars, the game *DOES* render like this:**
>   [image]

By doing this, you end up rendering less of the game, since sections are not being rendered and are being covered up by the black bars.
*This does Two things:*

- The game runs faster, with more FPS, compared with rendering all those pixels, and
- Allowing the game devs to increase graphic abilities without loss of FPS as much

  ---

## But why can you do it on PC?

**#PCMasterRace ;)**

Just kidding, the reason is that PC can be more powerful that ***PS3***, so they can handle rendering all the pixels easily if they have good specs. The developers then don't need to limit the resolution they can render, so they allowed to change them in the Debug settings. Of cours, they would like you to refrain from doing that (to allow this practice to be widely adopted), but they still gave them the chance anyway

---

Comment: Do you have a source for your assumptions? All other PS3 games work fine in 720p, even "down-graded" versions of PC or PS4 titles, like this one. What makes you think that The Evil Within couldn't run in 720p resolution, and that the cinematic effect is just a marketing ploy? Also, the PS4 and PC versions have the "cinematic" bars too, although they should be powerful enough for the game.

Comment: @Kodama Why do you think guns got bigger and bigger on consoles? Same concept. Hiding part of the scene to have to render less. Same goes for narrow FOV's of some games. All just happening to save computing time. Consoles are holding gaming back.

Comment: The reason they say it is a cinemtic experience is so they can hide the fact they are essentially lower the resolution being lowered, without actually lowering the resolution.

Comment: The developers on ReadyAtDawn, the guys who are making The Order 1886, are also doing the same thing in their game, limiting the Aspect Ratio from 16:9 to 2:40:1. According to kotako, they said that The Order was chosen to run this way to include 4xMSAA. Also quoted by Andrea Pessino (DEVELOPER), "4xMSAA which looks spectacular! x800 with AA looks MUCH better than x1080 without" and "x800 with 4xMSAA needs more bandwidth than x1080 would, so 1080 no MS would be cheaper." Also note Andrea confirmed that the game will run at a frame rate of 30fps

Comment: @Kodama, the aspect ratio is for all the games, regardless of platfrom (Unless you debug on your PC). The issue here is WHY the black bars exist, which is described above. If they only show the black bars on only the PS3 platform, people will complain that they are degrading the quality of one platform. To stop this, they just do it for all, stick a cinematic label, and all is good for them.

Comment: This is similar to what happened with Resident Evil 4, but on a lower scale.

Comment: So the PS3 is showing 720P, but rendering at 1080P? I'm not sure what terms are correct here. Basically from what I understand they added the black bars so they wouldn't have to render as much (thus being less stressful on the PS3/Xbox 360), and claimed it as a cinematic effect.

Comment: I'm probably going to get this game on PC, and get rid of the black bars with some mods I found. I understand why they did it, but it just looks god awful on smaller screens imo.

Comment: @KernelPanic, yes it does look awful. The PS3 is showing 720P (1280*720), but is acutally rendering less(1280*around 600). I am not sure for the PS3 version, it is 800 for the PS4 versions. Yes, the black bars would mean they render less so it is less stresfull and has a smaller toll on the FPS. I would recomend the PC version if your computer can handle it.

Comment: @Kodama, the game IS being showed at 720P, but since the bars block sections of the screen, the game itself is being rendered LESS than 720P. No scaling is used, just parts are chopped off.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness. I disagree with `Consoles are holding gaming back`. Have you seen Super Smash Bros. 4? The differences in graphics between the 3DS and Wii U are incomparably larger than the differences between PC and console on any other game, ***and*** both versions render in 60 FPS. Rather than `Consoles are holding gaming back`, I'd say it's more like `lazy devs who don't want to spend more time or effort on better graphics are holding gaming back`.

Comment: @Nolonar, I would never say consoles are holding gaming back, (I prefer consoles over PC any day), but it is important to understand that there ARE limitations on consoles, but that those limitations will have less of an effect when developers understand how to best code their game for their respective platform, whether it be PS, XBOX, WII U, 3DS etc.

Answer (score 1):

**YES, this IS possible on PS3.**

You can disable the cinematic black bars on all versions of The Evil Within, including the PS3, if you have downloaded the latest patch released June 2015.

In the pause menu select: options > graphics > letterbox > disabled.

[Source](http://www.bethblog.com/2015/06/23/the-evil-within-full-screen-title-update/)

As stated in the publishers official blog linked above the feature to remove the cinematic bars was based on fan feedback.

Comment: lol thanks for the downvote, I wonder who it was and why they did it? hmmm.

Comment: I wonder aswell @Colin